# jQuery .click() won't fire from an <a> within a mustache.js template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates, mustache

I'm experimenting with Mustache.js and I am unable to get a .click() event to fire from an  link that's rendered out from the template.

```
// click on tab to reveal information below
$(".tab").on("click", function(){
  var name = $(this).attr('data-name');
  var data = {"class":"lisa","name":"Lisa Jones","age":"http://lisajones.com","address":{"streetAddress":"88 High Street","city":"Birmingham","postCode":"B1 2AA"},"workNumber":"+44 1234 474747","contactableAtHome":false,"personalNumbers":[{"type":"tel","number":"+44 1234 111222"},{"type":"mobile","number":"+44 7987 444555"}],"biography":"lisa ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."};

    var template = $('#infoContact').html();
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
    $('#content').html(html);

});

// everytime an a is clicked this should fire
$("a").on("click", function(){
  alert("An <a> tag has been clicked on...")
});

</script>

<script id="infoContact" type="text/template">
  <div class="side-panel">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">But if you click on this nothing happens...</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</script>
```

As you can see above, clicking on an a link anywhere should fire an alert.  Any ideas?

Comment: you have to bind event once element is added to the DOM otherwise your selector return jquery empty object. Or delegate event to any static ancestor

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using a templating language the element will be created dynamically, so try [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function () {
    alert("An <a> tag has been clicked on...")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the anchor needs to be on the page when that code runs for the click to be attached.

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(){
  alert("An <a> tag has been clicked on...")
});
```

Comment: please answer my question , have the same situation , it works for me but on everything :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53601023/jquery-on-click-working-on-every-thing