# Jquery On() 'click' working on every thing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, mustache, jquery-events

I have a problem which drive me crazy :(
Couldnt figure it out why!

Here is my HTML and Mustache

```
<section id="slideShow">
    <script id="slideShow-template" type="text/template">
        <ul>
            {{#slideShow}}
            <li class="{{{class}}}">
                <img src="{{{img}}}" alt="{{{title}}}">
                <a href="{{{link}}}">
                    <h1 class="slideShowTitle">{{title}}</h1>
                    <p class="slideShowDate">{{date}}</p>
                    <p class="slideShowDetail">{{detail}}</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            {{/slideShow}}
        </ul>
        <nav>
            {{#slideShow}}
                <a href="javascript:;"></a>
            {{/slideShow}}
        </nav>
        <a href="javscript:void(0)" class="prevSlide"></a>
        <a href="javscript:void(0)" class="nextSlide"></a>
        
    </script>
</section>
```

and here is the JS

```
(function() {

    var slideShow = {
        slideShow: [
        ],

        init: function() {
            this.cacheDom();
            this.bindEvents();
            this.render();
        },

        bindEvents: function() {
            this.$el.on('click', this.$next, function(){
                alert('sdsd')
            })
        },

        render: function() {
            var data = {
                slideShow: this.slideShow
            };
            this.$el.html(Mustache.render(this.template, data));
        },

        cacheDom: function() {
            this.$el = $('#slideShow');
            this.$ul = this.$el.find('ul');
            this.$li = this.$ul.find('li');
            this.$nav = this.$el.find('nav');
            this.$a = this.$nav.find('a');
            this.$next = this.$el.find('.nextSlide');
            this.$prev = this.$el.find('.prevSlide');
            this.template = $('#slideShow-template').html();
        }

    };

    slideShow.init();

})();
```

**as you see with `bindEvents()`, I'm trying to bind click function to the dynamically generated `.nextSlide` tag but it works on whole parent (`#slideShow`)
what am I missing?**

[**THE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ns4t8mcv/)

Comment: it doesnt work for dynamic elements,

Comment: but on many many tutorials and examples people dont do it this way? if so ? whats the point of passing the targeted parameter ??

Comment: According to the JQuery documentation: (http://api.jquery.com/on/) you are setting up the event handling correctly and it should only fire for the child elements, are you sure you aren't mistakenly clicking one of the children?

Comment: this is really annoying, Im pretty sure, I double checked , I think its about mustache or the template rendering

Comment: it only works with the depreciated .live() on older jquery or I should add bunch of if after it , Im searching for 2 hours :(

Comment: do you have a working fiddle for it ?

Comment: its mustache can I bulid one ? let me try

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ns4t8mcv/

Comment: In bindEvents, the second parameter passed into `this.$el.on` is *not* a selector.

Comment: nope, I tried , it binds but it binds to everything , the whole parent, I have a fiddle plz check

Comment: Correct because you don't have a selector

Comment: would you correct it in the fiddle, when I try it gives me the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
    this.$el.on('click', this.$next, function(){
        alert('sdsd')
    })
```

to this:

```
    this.$el.on('click', '.nextSlide', function(){
        alert('sdsd')
    })
```

Comment: is there any method I can use on this.$next to change it directly to '.nextSlide' ?

Comment: No because there are many many selectors that can lead to your one element.  Why not change this.next to be just the selector instead of the element.

Comment: Im trying to write as modular as I can, define my vars and Dom elements in one place, kinda trying to adopt my self this way

Comment: Without digging in too deeply I assume there is a reason that delegated handling is being used here, ie, `<some parent node>.on('click', selector, func)` rather than just directly binding ie `this.$next.on('click', func)` - so I would say that this.$next might not even contain anything if the next button is added to the DOM after the cacheDOM function has been run.

Comment: dear James now I have another problem which Im dealing with it another 3 hours, Im trying to set the css position of these dynamic elements , my cacheDom method on the code above is running before DOM load, and many of the variables (like this.$ul) are undefined  , even after putting the whole code in $(document).ready( function(){...}) I still cant use  the dynamic one, so I should figure out a way to really point my selectors to current state after load, I even tried .on('ready' ... ) like your solution but no success
Im really looking for clean and not repeating solutions not setTimeout ..

Comment: I suspect that you will need to use [delegated event handlers](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for all your clicks and forget about using this.$ul, etc, entirely.

Comment: This time its not about clicking or event, its styling , like this.$ul.css('left' , ,.....) OR
this.$li.css('width', (100 / slideNumbers) + '%');
Im trying to understand why the code doesnt work inside $document.ready()
and is there a way to force some dynamic element run after DOM being ready at the same command line. not scoping everything ... thanks for the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184657/discussion-between-cameron-a-and-james).

Comment: The references you create in this.cachedom do not work because their elements do not exist at the time.  Some of the elements they refer to might be destroyed and re-created during the natural operation of the slideshow.  It’s simply not safe to use those references.  Thats why you must use a selector every time.